# How to avoid TypeInitializer Exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, typeinitializeexception

In the application there are 2 pages, CompletePoll.aspx, Default.aspx.

**CompletePoll.aspx --> Page_Load()**

```
          Ultoo u = new Ultoo();
          u.UserName = Request["username"].ToString();
          u.Password = Request["password"].ToString();
          new Thread(u.CompletePoll).Start();
```

**CompletePoll()**

```
          .......
          .......
          String str = "Question:" + QuestionGenerator.GetNextQuestion(); /*Here i am getting Type initializer exception*/
          .......
          .......
```

**QuestionGenerator**

```
          public static class QuestionGenerator
          {
               private static string[] FirstParts = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/QuestionPart1.txt")).ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
               private static string[] SecondParts = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/QuestionPart2.txt")).ReadToEnd(). Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
               private static Random r = new Random();

               public static string GetNextQuestion()
               {
                    return FirstParts[r.Next(0, FirstParts.Length - 1)] + " " + SecondParts[r.Next(0, SecondParts.Length - 1)] + "?";
               }
          }
```

But if i am calling Default.aspx first and then CompletePoll.aspx the code is working fine.

**Default.aspx --> Page_Load()**

```
         Label1.Text = QuestionGenerator.GetNextQuestion();
```

So here my problem is if i am accessing CompletePoll.aspx **first** i am getting TypeInitializer Exception. If i am accessing Default.aspx first and then CompletePoll.aspx, I am not getting any problem. Whats wrong in my code, am i missing something? How can i access CompletePoll.aspx first?

Comment: InnerException: System.NullReferenceException HResult=-2147467261 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Source=WebTracing StackTrace: at UltooAgent.QuestionGenerator..cctor() in c:\Users\Rajeev\Desktop\Tracing\Tracing\Tracing\WebTracing\WebTracing\QuestionGe‌​nerator.cs:line 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> private static string[] FirstParts = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/QuestionPart1.txt")).ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
> ```

That isn't right. This checks `HttpContext.Current` once, when the type is initialised, saves the result, and never attempts to read it again. The never checking again can be correct when the first time succeeds, but the first time will require `HttpContext.Current` to not be `null`. If the first attempt causes an exception, it won't be reinitialised later. You cannot be sure when exactly the class gets initialised, so you cannot be sure whether `HttpContext.Current` is set at that point (and it won't be if you call it from a thread).

Also, this does not call `StreamReader.Dispose`, so it will leave the reader and file itself open until the garbage collector happens to run.

A safer way would be something like

```
private static string[] firstParts; // field

private static string[] FirstParts // property
{
    get
    {
        if (firstParts == null)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("App_Data/QuestionPart1.txt")))
                firstParts = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        }
        return firstParts;
    }
}
```

This will make sure `reader.Dispose()` gets called, will make sure the file is read when the property is first accessed instead of when the type is initialised, will make sure any exceptions actually tell you what's going on in a more straightforward way, and will make sure the rest of the type is usable even if `FirstParts` cannot get set.

However, it still requires that you do not read `FirstParts` from a thread. You can avoid that problem by reading it once before starting the thread:

```
Ultoo u = new Ultoo();
u.UserName = Request["username"].ToString();
u.Password = Request["password"].ToString();
QuestionGenerator.Initialize(); // from the main thread
new Thread(u.CompletePoll).Start();


public static class QuestionGenerator
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var firstParts = FirstParts;
        var secondParts = SecondParts;
        // merely reading the properties is enough to initialise them, so ignore the results
    }
}
```

Once the thread has started, after `Initialize()` has been called, you can access `FirstParts` and `SecondParts` reliably.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information, I made changes as you said and it worked for me.

 By the way i also found another solution which will allow me to find the path of the file "QuestionParts1.txt" without using HttpContext.Current object. Following is the property which i can use from a thread to find the path.

      HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath+@"App_Data\QuestionPart1.txt"

Comment: @Rajeev That looks good too. If you take that route, I would personally recommend `Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "App_Data", "QuestionPart1.txt")`, but simple string concatenation as you're doing should give the same result in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the inner exception. A TypeInitializerException simply means an exception has been thrown from inside a constructor. The exception would be generated from the code contained within the call to QuestionGenerator.GetNextQuestion();

Comment: InnerException: System.NullReferenceException
       HResult=-2147467261
       Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       Source=WebTracing
       StackTrace:
            at UltooAgent.QuestionGenerator..cctor() in c:\Users\Rajeev\Desktop\Tracing\Tracing\Tracing\WebTracing\WebTracing\QuestionGenerator.cs:line 12
       InnerException: